# JQuery reset select2 in modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have tried the way like this to reset select2 in my modal, but It does not work.

```
$(".payment-method").select2('data', null);

<div class="modal-body"> 
                  <form class="form-horizontal" id="category-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                          <label>Payment Methods (Untuk kebutuhan tertentu)</label>
                          <div class="dropdown">
                            <select class="form-control payment-method" name="paymentType" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select the payment method">
                              <option value="1">cash</option>
                              <option value="2">credit</option>
                              <option value="3">debit</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Do you want to clear the filter, or reinitialize the entire `<select>` element? If the latter is the case, you might want to [destroy it (i.e. `.select2('destroy')`)](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control) before calling `.select2()` again.

Comment: Reset as in clear the selection? Also what version of select2 are you using?

Comment: @Terry I choose data in my modal using select2, when I close and re-open my modal again, my select2 select the data before, so I want to clear all the data when I re-open my modal

Comment: @apokryfos how to check the version? I am new in programming world

Comment: It should be written in the JS source of what you're including. If you're using a CDN (linking the source directly) it might be part of the URL, if it's not then it's probably version 4 something

Comment: Sorry I didn't see wel your question & didn't see the "Reset" part, however can we have the code of your modal ?!

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi sure..
I have editted my question.. You can see my modal now

Comment: @apokryfos yes, I am using version 4.0.3

Comment: @Terry I can't use destroy. If I use destroy, When I re-open my modal.. My select2 will be destroyed

Comment: Did you read the other half of my original comment... *[...] before calling `.select2()` again*? Reinitialize your select2 when you open the modal.

Comment: select2 version 4+ will listen on events on the underlying select so if you do something like `$(".payment-method").val([]).trigger("change")` that should be reflected in the select2 select as well

Comment: @Terry I destroy it then call select2() again, but still same

Comment: @apokryfos woah, thankyou.. it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".payment-method").val([]).trigger("change"); //Answered by apokryfos
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Select2 `4.x` just trigger change.select2

```
$('.payment-method').val(1).trigger('change.select2');
```